# Wordmark logo design principles

Tags: print-design, logo, gradient, design-principles

Can a wordmark logo type be in gradient color and have an underscore  to separate  the initial?

Comment: Sometimes yes. Sometimes no. If it's a good idea in your case we can't say without any information.

Answer (score 1):

It can be tested. Check what score it gets

[image]

Comment: I could use a Googi Gola right now.